# Jquery showing hidden content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IszKj

What I want to do is how it so when I click on either `any status` or `any date` I open up a hidden div which gives a list of options.

My question is, how do I approach this in the best way?

1. Do I have two different divs and then open the one which is relevant to the list item which was clicked:

```html
<div id="status" style="display: hidden">Option 1 Option 2</div>
<div id="date" style="display: hidden">Option 1 Option 2</div>
```

2. Do I have one div and only show the content inside it which is relevant to that button?

```html
<div style="hidden">
<span id="status">...</span> 
<span id="date">...</span> 
</div>
```

In addition to this, should I be using `toggle` or the traditional `open` / `close` function.

It would be nice for it to be degradable if JS is disabled.

Comment: Do you load the content dynamically?
Is there any situation when you want to show both?

Comment: I don't load the content dynamically and there is no situation where I would want both

Comment: It's totally unto you how you want to display it… i don't think there will be much difference in performance between showing to separate divs and showing a common div and displaying the content in it.. in small scale, especially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, how do I approach this in the best way?

In your particular use-case, it is better that you use different blocks for each of those options.

In fact, as @mh-itc pointed out, it is better if you use nested list i.e. `ul` instead of `div` inside those `li`s.

Also, you may use `a` instead of `span`.

> It would be nice for it to be degradable if JS is disabled.

This can be achieved by deferring the `display:none;` until the JavaScript is loaded and run.

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/928Dj/***

*Markup*:

```
<div>
    <ul id="filter">
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="dropdown">Any status ▾</a>
            <ul class="opt">
                <li><label><input type="checkbox" />Status 1</label></li>
                <li><label><input type="checkbox" />Status 2</label></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="dropdown">Any date ▾</a>
            <ul class="opt">
                <li><label><input type="checkbox" />Date 1</label></li>
                <li><label><input type="checkbox" />Date 2</label></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

*CSS*:

```
ul {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
#filter {
    display: inline-block;
}
#filter > li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    padding-right: 12px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
ul.opt.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

*jQuery Code*:

```
// comment out to see how it degrades without javascript
$("ul.opt").addClass("hidden");
$('#filter > li > a').on("click", function(e) {
      $(this).next('ul').toggle();
});
```

**Note**: In the demo, un-comment the JavaScript code to see how it will behave when JavaScript is available. And comment out to see how it degrades when JavaScript isn't available.

Answer (score 4):

**Created a Fiddle for you:**

http://jsfiddle.net/e4mQD/1/

***HTML:***

```
<div style="display: block;
height: 40px;">
    <ul id="filter">
        <li>
            <span>Any status▾</span>
            <ul class="options">
                <li>Option1</li>
                <li>Option2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>Any date▾</span>
            <ul class="options">
                <li>OptionA</li>
                <li>OptionB</li>
            </ul>    
        </li>
    </ul>
```

***CSS:***

```
#filter, .options {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.options {
  display:none;
}

.options li {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

***JavaScript:***

```
$('#filter li').click(function(){
  $(this).find('.options').toggle();
});
```

Comment: This works but the use of an id that isn't unique is not allowed, use classes instead of an id

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Very stuped mistake, I corrected it :)

Comment: Here's an improved version (http://jsfiddle.net/e4mQD/2/) because the original version had some shortcomings, like triggering the toggle when you clicked an option which would be bad when these are inputs like checkboxes or radios

Comment: @Jimmy there's also a work-aroung using input checkbox instead of JS/jQuery: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jfAoa Work's from IE9+

Answer (score 3):

`display:hidden` 
is not valid css rule. You need to use `display:none`

Comment: if you are using bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/css/) you can also add the class "hidden" to your element instead.

Comment: Thank you for the correction, but this still doesn't help me with the implementation

Comment: That's why I *commented* on the solution, providing information that OP might not have thought about for his solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep accessibility in mind change the hidden status when loading the site with javascript, if you do that user that have add-ons like NoScript active get to see every option without loosing functionality.
People who use NoScript tend to dislike sites that force them to deactivate NS to use it properly.

For your solution I suggest to use two separate divs, with this you have the option to show both boxes at the same time and have a styled version that makes clear, that these are separate.
Add a class like "optionbox" to these and throw your css rules in there instead of making a rule with `#date, #status`